# hive giving inconsistent results when run twice

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to compare a copied table in hadoop-hive (external to hive-internal comparison) to see if there are any errors. Therefore I did the following query:

```
SELECT 'column1',
       ext.my_string,
       hive.my_string,
       ext.my_string == hive.my_string
FROM

    (SELECT concat_ws('' , collect_list(cast(column1 as string))) as my_string
    FROM landing.{base_table_name}_ext) AS ext

    JOIN

    (SELECT concat_ws('' , collect_list(cast(column1 as string))) as my_string
    FROM sandbox.{base_table_name}) AS hive

UNION ALL

SELECT 'column2',
       ext.my_string,
       hive.my_string,
       ext.my_string == hive.my_string
FROM

    (SELECT concat_ws('' , collect_list(cast(column2 as string))) as my_string
    FROM landing.{base_table_name}_ext) AS ext

    JOIN

    (SELECT concat_ws('' , collect_list(cast(column2 as string))) as my_string
    FROM sandbox.{base_table_name}) AS hive

UNION ALL ...
```

The total number of columns and therefore UNION ALLs is around 50 and the rows of the table are around 30'000. When I run the query some columns are different. If I run it again, the columns with differences oddly change (as if dependent on a random process). Although there are 3 columns which are objectively different and they always show up as different.

I cannot understand why the answer changes and why there are always some few false positives as there are no explicit random functions here.

Is it because of the way Hive manages each node's task?

Would this happen on a centralized system as opposed to a distributed one?

Comment: Are the number of columns the same?  Are the number of rows the same?  If so, the result sets are probably the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the 2 tables have the same size (e. i. number of rows and columns). Yes they are probably the same but sometimes oddly enough there are false positives. As if the collect_list() function collects the values in another order, perhaps...

Comment: @GordonLinoff: if I take a false positive and run the query only for that column, then it will run fine, why????